# Trying to Dual Boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I've looked in many places and still trying to figure out why I cant complete an installation of ubuntu 16 with my Dell Inspiron 17-7778 laptop. I used Rufus to create a bootable drive and was able to get to the installation and get all the way through it until is tries to install grub2. It fails the installation and all I can do is send bug reports. I ran boot-repair and got this diagnostic: http://paste2.org/D42jmXjt

Apparently says no boot loader is installed and I am still not sure why. When I went through the installation I did the manual choice and created / (50GB) /home (~350GB) and Swap (4GB).

I also tried turning off Secure Boot and Fast Startup. Still no luck. It is a UEFI laptop and the bootable flash drive is setup for UEFI. Any ideas or direction would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It says no boot loader is installed *in the MBR of `/dev/sda`.* That's an extremely important "if" clause, because there are *two* ways most modern computers can boot:

- **BIOS/CSM/legacy mode** -- This method places the boot loader in the MBR of a hard disk (typically `/dev/sda`, from Linux's perspective). This is the old method of booting and is *not used* on most new computers as they ship from the factory. Most new computers still support this boot mode, but installing Ubuntu in this way is ill-advised if you intend to dual-boot with a pre-installed OS such as Windows.
- **EFI/UEFI mode** -- This is the native boot mode of most modern computers. In EFI-mode booting, the boot loader is stored as an ordinary file (or files) on the [EFI System Partition,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is a FAT partition on the hard disk. Your Boot Repair output indicates that Ubuntu's default boot loader (GRUB) is installed on your ESP (`/dev/sda1` in your case), along with Windows' boot loader.

A quick look at your Boot Repair output reveals no obvious problems; it looks like your computer *should* be booting to GRUB, and from there to Ubuntu. OTOH, the fact that you got an error message about boot loader installation suggests that something went wrong that the installer detected, so I may be missing something, or there could be a real problem that's not showing up in the Boot Repair output. It could also be that the error message at installation is a red herring. (It's known to be overly sensitive sometimes.)

Since Boot Repair has failed, I recommend you try this as an alternative:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (That page provides links to both types of images.)
2. Prepare a boot medium from the rEFInd image you download.
3. Boot with the rEFInd image. With any luck, it will show you options for booting to both Windows and Ubuntu.
4. Test both boot paths.
5. If you can boot both Ubuntu and Windows with rEFInd, boot to Ubuntu.
6. In Ubuntu, install rEFInd using either the Debian package or the PPA.
7. Unplug the rEFInd USB drive or CD-R and reboot.

With any luck, rEFInd will come up and enable you to boot. If rEFInd does not appear at this point, then that means there's something wrong with your firmware, or perhaps your firmware's boot options are corrupted. Dell normally does a decent job with its EFIs, so my guess would be damaged settings. Going into the firmware and resetting everything to the default may help overcome this problem. At this point, booting to Ubuntu and typing `sudo refind-install` or re-running Boot Repair may get you going again.